# Exclude bot users from slack search api results

Tags: slack, slack-api

In the slack UI, when I make a search, it makes a request to the `search.modules` endpoint. There's also the option to exclude apps and bots from the result, which translates to a boolean POST param to that api endpoint.

https://api.slack.com/methods doesn't list such a method, and only has `search.messages`, `search.files`, and `search.all`.

How can I use the API to search, but exclude bot accounts? Do I need to leverage this seemingly hidden `search.modules` (which probably is inaccessible with a bot acct)? Is there a better way than making a list of bots and manually filtering them out of search results?

Answer (score 5):

Well it's not in the documentation anywhere, but I can achieve this with the `search.messages` api by adding `search_exclude_bots=True` to my POST data.

Since this is undocumented, I'm curious as to whether users *should* be using this param and if it will be changed in a breaking way in the future.